# Is it possible to dynamically initialize an array using "java.lang.reflect.Array" dynamically in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I want to dynamically initialize an array having a size as specified by the user.

Comment: Can you better clarify what exactly you mean? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use java.lang.reflect.Array class to create an array.
See the following code where we can create an array of int.

```
int[] intArray = (int[]) java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(int.class, 5);
```

The first parameter is the type of each element in the array.
The second parameter indicates the number of elements in the array.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to initialise the array to a size specified by the user, just use a variable for the size.

```
int size = 3;
int[] array = new int[size];
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the size of your array:");
    int arraySize = sc.nextInt();

    int[] yourArray = new int[arraySize];
    //Do something with your array
}
```

Note that this does not check for invalid input. You should add checks to confirm the input is actually **positive** and an **integer**.